# How to change a window layout on a button press?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

what I am asking is when writing WPF applications in C# how can I get it so on a press of the menu bar the window changes to a different layout with different feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use a TabControl, see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.tabcontrol(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: TabControl worked very well